# Given a set of powers of two, how "close" can we come to a prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics

Given a natural $n \ge 2$, we can construct a set of all powers of two from $2^n$ to $2^{4n}$:

$$\{2^n, 2^{n+1}, 2^{n+2}, \dots, 2^{4n}\}$$

**How close does one of these numbers come to a prime in the worst case?**

**AN EXAMPLE**

For example, if $n=2$, the set is:

$$\{2^2, 2^3, 2^4, 2^5, 2^6, 2^7, 2^8\}$$

$2^2=4$ is $1$ away from 5, and we can't get any closer for any power of two, so the answer is $1$.

**WHAT I'M TRYING TO FIND**

I'm looking for an upper bounds for the distance we can get from elements of the set (any set that fits the description above) to a prime.  In other words, for a set that fits the description, and in a really bad scenario, where all the primes are far from the set, how close will they be to the set?

Comment: By [Bertrand's Postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) there's always a prime between any two consecutive powers of $2$. Therefore it's at most $2^{n-1}$ (a prime exactly in the middle of the first interval).

Comment: All Fermat Primes and all Mersenne primes are within 1 of a power of two.

Answer (score 2):

[Opperman's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppermann%27s_conjecture) would imply that there is at least one prime between $2^n$ and $2^n + 2^{n/2}$ [EDIT] if $n$ is even.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this implication is proven, exactly? How do we show that there are perfect squares and/or "pronic" numbers "near" $2^n$ (i.e., in the case $n$ is odd)?

Comment: Hmm.  Looks like I should have said "for even $n$".  If $n$ is odd, Opperman doesn't quite give that.If $x = \lceil 2^{n/2} \rceil$,  $x^2 + x < (2^{n/2}+1)^2 + (2^{n/2}+1) = 2^n + 3 \cdot 2^{n/2} + 2$, so Opperman would say there is a prime between $2^n$ and that.  There is no prime between $2^3$ and $2^3 + 2^{3/2}$.

Comment: Indeed. see this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3950164/is-there-always-a-prime-p-which-falls-short-of-2n-by-at-most-a-square-root thanks.